# How does a browser transpile JSX?

Tags: html, reactjs, babeljs

I read [the W3schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_getstarted.asp) and have some questions regarding how how a browser transpiled the html file.

example.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin</script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id="mydiv"></div>
  <script type="text/babel">
      function Hello() {
          return <h1>Hello World!</h1>;
      }
      ReactDOM.render(<Hello/>, document.getElementById('mydiv'))
  </script>
</body>
```

When I do inspect in chome, I saw this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin=""></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin=""></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script>"use strict";
        function Hello() {
            return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("h1", null, "Hello World!");
        }
        ReactDOM.render( /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(Hello, null), document.getElementById('mydiv'));
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mydiv">
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </div>
    <script type="text/babel">
        function Hello() {
            return <h1>Hello World!</h1>;
        }
        ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('mydiv'))
    </script>
  </body>
```

A few questions:

1. Is it true, that `babel.min.js` sets up a listener, which upon script loading completion, picked out the `<script type="text/babel">` part and translated it into a legit js, and stuck it under `<head>` section?
2. The original `<script type="text/babel">` is left inplace and it wouldn't be run by browser anymore? why?
3. Can someone explain step by step what actually happened?

Comment: Scripts without a specified type or `type="text/javascript"` gets automatically executed by the browser, otherwise it'll be left alone. Babel finds all JSX type scripts (`type="text/babel"`), and if they're inline, gets the content then runs it, otherwise it seems an AJAX request, gets the content, then runs it. So no to your first question. Be advised though, this is the least ideal way to use Babel, and you definitely shouldn't use this in production. Hope that answers all you questions.

Comment: @code how come I saw translated js code which were not in my original html then?

Comment: You can see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your questions one by one...

1. No to the first part, yes to the second. See, scripts without a specified type or `type="text/javascript"` gets automatically executed by the browser, otherwise it'll be left alone. If it's an external script with an unrecognized type, the browser won't load it either. Babel queries all your Babel scripts from the document (e.g. `document.querySelectorAll('[type="text/babel"]')`), and if they're inline, Babel transpiles them, then sticks the real Javascript in the HTML head, otherwise Babel sends an AJAX request, them does its magic.
2. As I mentioned, the browser will leave scripts with unrecognized type alone, so Babel scripts don't get executed by the browser.
3. I think #1 answered this question.

So there you have it. Be advised though, this is the least ideal way to use Babel, and you definitely shouldn't use this in production (you should pretranspile it).

Comment: thank you, yes this answers the questions. I assume babel changes .html via manipulating DOMs? if so, the transpiled script was picked up/executed by the browser the moment it was inserted under <head> via babel's DOM manipulation?

Comment: @user98056 yep!